# Best package to manage backup / recovery of a web application with database, to a remote server?

Tags: mysql, backup, replication, backup-restoration

We need to manage automated backup and restoration of multiple websites, most built on PHP / MySQL, hosted on different servers across the globe. All the backups will be made to a single remote server. All servers run on Linux.

I was thinking of rdiff-backup with mysqldumps and replication, but we need to get this up and running quickly, so we require an out-of-the-box solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good one:
http://www.backup-manager.org/about/

**EDIT (I see no one read the about page):**

Easy and automatic operation

```
* 1 configuration file, 5 minutes setup.
* Manually invoke backup process or run daily unattended via CRON.
```

Comprehensive Backup

```
* Backup files, MySQL databases and Subversion repositories.
* Specify multiple targets to backup at once (/etc, /home, etc…).
* Ability to exclude files from backup.
* Automatically purge old backups.
```

Backup Methods

```
* Full backup only or Full + Incremental backup.
* Backup to an attached disk, LAN or Internet.
* Burns backup to CD/DVD with MD5 checksum verification.
* Archives in lots of open formats: tar, gzip, bzip2, lzma, dar, zip.
* Slice archives to 2 GB if using dar archives format.
```

Secure

```
* Backup over SSH.
* Encrypts archives.
* Offsite remote upload of archives via FTP, SSH, RSYNC or Amazon S3.
```

Advanced

```
* Can run with different configuration files concurrently.
* Easy external hooks.
```

Restoration

```
* Simply uncompressed the open format backup archives with any command line or GUI tool.
```

Answer (score 1):

for the mysqldumps, use automysqldump : it's very configurable. For the code tree, a cron script doing something like the following:

tar cvf - my_www_dir | ssh user@remotehost "cat > mywwwdump.tar"

I'm using this method for a few servers I administer and it works well.

Tid

Answer (score 0):

what are your concerns about rdiff-backup?  I've been using it successfully to backup web-sites and MySQL databases (database dumps) for the past year and a half with not real issues.  The incremental backups work beautifully and the restore process have saved my neck twice.

Good luck!